# problems with applicationContext.xml, setting up Hibernate, Spring MVC, and MySql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, maven-2

I am trying to setup SpringMVC 3.0 + Hibernate + MySql with Maven.
Having frustrating issues with the applicationContext.xml.
The controller to the service to the DAO works, just that I am having problems setting up Hibernate to MySql.

Googled lots of stuff online but different tutorials have different instructions so I'm all messed up now.

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ray.service.blog" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<bean id="blogDao" class="com.ray.service.blog.dao.BlogDao">
    <!-- <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property> -->
    <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="blogService" class="com.ray.service.blog.services.BlogService" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ray" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
```

Here's the first few lines of the stack trace:

```
[2012-01-04 10:17:27,265] ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blogController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.ray.service.blog.controllers.BlogController.setBlogService(com.ray.service.blog.services.BlogService); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blogService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.ray.service.blog.services.BlogService.setBlogDao(com.ray.service.blog.dao.BlogDao); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blogDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
```

Let me know if you need more information... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the error add this to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

To improve your connection try using something like this

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ray" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
```

and in the pom.xml you need to add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

In our projects we usually use this definition or the one from c3p0

**Future:**
Consider adding the following properties to have pooled connection

```
<property name="initialSize" value="${hibernate.initialSize}" />
<property name="minIdle" value="${hibernate.minIdle}" />
<property name="maxActive" value="${hibernate.maxActive}" />
```

And have look at this bean to export your configuration properties to dedicated files

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:hibernate_jdbc.properties</value>  
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing a binding for [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html).

Hibernate switched to slf4j in 3.3.x.

Add one of the bindings listed [here](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#where_is_binding) to your project's classpath/pom.xml and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the culprit is NoClassDefFoundError. org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.
You need to include the appropriate jar in the classpath.  The hibernate extract you have should have an slf4j jar.